# Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=A$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=B$, {$c_n$}: $c_{2n-1}=a_n$ and $c_{2n} = b_n$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n=A+B$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=A$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=B$, also, define {$c_n$} as: $c_{2n-1}=a_n$ and $c_{2n} = b_n$ for $1 \leq n$. Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n=A+B$$

Can I get help on how to rigurously prove this?

Assume that $S_n$ and $T_n$ are the partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$, respectively, we know that $S_n \longrightarrow A$ and $T_n \longrightarrow B$, so, how can I prove that if $U_n$ is the partial sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$, then, $U_n \longrightarrow A+B$?

Comment: $U_{2n}=S_n+T_n$ and $U_{2n-1}=S_n+T_{n-1}$

Comment: Using previous comment $U_{2n}-(A+B)=(S_n-A)+(T_n-B)$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Given any $e>0:$ Take $n_1$ such that $\forall n\ge n_1\,(\, |S_n-A|<e/2\,)$ and take $n_2$ such that $\forall n\ge n_2\,(\, |T_n-B|<e/2\,).$

Let $n_3=2\cdot \max (n_1,n_2).$ Now for any $n\ge n_3:$

(i). If $n$ is even then $n/2\ge n_1$ and $n/2\ge n_2$ so $$|U_n-(A+B)|=|(S_{n/2}-A)+(T_{n/2}-B)|\le |(S_{n/2}-A)|+|(T_{n/2}-B)|<$$ $$<e/2+e/2=e.$$ (ii). If $n$ is odd then $(n+1)/2>n_1$ and $(n-1)/2\ge n_2$ so $$|U_n-(A+B)|=|(S_{(n+1)/2}-A)+(T_{(n-1)/2}-B)|\le |(S_{(n+1)/2}-A)|+|(T_{(n-1)/2}-B)|<$$ $$<e/2+e/2=e.$$